# Is there any way to add a type constraint to a generic class from a variable?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to add a type constraint to a generic class from a variable?

```
class GenericClass<{X}>
{
}
```

where {X} is for example an array of types like: Object1, Object2, String

Comment: What do you want to use this for? Hopefully we can suggest alternatives

Comment: I believe I just answered my own question, I can use text templates to generate these classes where I can define the types I need as an array.

Comment: You can generate static .cs files and then load them or use [System.Reflection.Emit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/emitting-dynamic-methods-and-assemblies) effectively creating your type at runtime. Perhaps you can use [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) too

Comment: Not really a possibility to create objects at runtime for this solution.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
class Class1 : IConstraint {}

class Class2 : IConstraint {}

interface IConstraint {}

class MustHaveConstraints<T> where T : IConstraint {}
```

If your types are only classes this kind of implementation will be more flexable.

**UPDATE**

As @DRapp suggested, this can be done with classes as well. Basically when you define a generic type, you can add restriction of usage with constraints. For more detail please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

Comment: Aside from interface, the WHERE could apply to a base class that other classes are derived from.  I would suggest you edit your answer and show that scenario too...  Ex: Class Animal, subclass Dog, Cat, etc... they are all animals and each can have its own customized components too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't constraint on an array.

An array is not really a type, it is a *false* type: a raw basic memory data structure like a train with wagoons as cells even if `Array` is a class to manipulate them.

In IL generated code, the usage of `new` keyword is transposed in `newarr` operand:

- class types: no instance is created, only cells allocation for references that are null by default.
- value types: no instance is created, only cells allocation for values.

Generic type argument constraint must be done on a *real* type.

You can use a `List` instead that is a generic oriented object implementation of the concept of an array (it is in fact a wrapper to an array).

You can write for example:

```
class MustHaveConstraints<X>
where X : List<string>` 
{
}
```

But it is useless.

Therefore you can write:

```
class MustHaveConstraints<T1, T2>
where T1: List<T2>
{
}

var instance1 = new MustHaveConstraints<List<object>, object>();
var instance2 = new MustHaveConstraints<List<int>, int>();
var instance3 = new MustHaveConstraints<List<string>, string>();
var instance4 = new MustHaveConstraints<List<bool[]>, bool[]>();
```

---

```
static void Test()
{
  var arr1 = new int[10];
  var arr2 = new List<int>[10];
  var arr3 = new Data[10];
  var instance = new List<int>();
}

public struct Data
{
  public int Value;
}
```

```
// _ = new int[10];
IL_0000: ldc.i4.s 10
IL_0002: newarr [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_0007: pop
// _ = new List<int>[10];
IL_0008: ldc.i4.s 10
IL_000a: newarr class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>
IL_000f: pop
// _ = new Data[10];
IL_0010: ldc.i4.s 10
IL_0012: newarr ConsoleApp.Program/Data
IL_0017: pop
// new List<int>();
IL_0018: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::.ctor()
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newarr

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newobj

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to my own question, yes it possible but not in the conventional way. One would have to use text templates to generate these classes

```
<#@ var types = "T1, T2, T3"; #>
namespace Generics 
{ 
    class GenericClass<<#=types#>> 
    { 
    } 
}
```